# Why do I have strange property name when using google oauth api?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm setting up a web app (javascript) that allows a user to log in with Google OAuth API. I need to retrieve Youtube Data and Google Account Data. I use these scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl openid

I get the data but the properties names are strange, take a look :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP7HW.png

```
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest"];
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl openid'; 
function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
        console.log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get());
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()); 
    });
}
```

How to have properties names like "firstname", "lastname", and so on... in the currentUser property ...

Excuse me if my English is not perfect ^^

Comment: your image is showing `.getAuthInstance()` instead of `.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get()`

Comment: It's the same problem, when I perform this :     .getAuthInstance().currentUser.get() ...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, I find a new page in the google doc that explain how to use property, I have to call method like getId() or getName() on a GoogleUser object and no trying to reach the properties directly.